# Facebook Like button and MySQL database

Tags: facebook

I want to take the numbers of likes and saving it in a database when a user liked something in the database to add +1 and when a user does not like to be removed from the database to the numbers of -1 likes, this should be done in real time ... at least I think so, if there is a way otherwise be arranged from most liked to least liked, please help me :S

I did an illustration **:-*)***

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mlFz.jpg

p.s.: I hope, I explained it well, at least as for a blonde :D

Comment: you can do it with the facebook javascript sdk. check the examples/tutorials there...

Answer (score 1):

To get number of `likes` for particular page you can perform FQL

```
SELECT like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="url is here"
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat