# Adding another function to the facebook like api?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, facebook

Is there anyway to add another function to the Facebook 'like' button API? I want to log popularity, so it would add a 1 to a MYSQL field using PHP when pressed, aswell as submitting the like to Facebook. This is the Facebook like script:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">
</script><fb:like href="#" show_faces="true" width="450" font=""></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a callback to the like button using the following js

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget, response) {
    //Query database server and do stuff
});
```

In this callback you could query your server via ajax to manipulate your database

(Source: [Facebook "Like" button callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798622/facebook-like-button-callback))

Answer (score 0):

Use [Facebook Insights](http://www.wisnet.com/noteworthy/using-facebook-insights-to-track-the-like-button-box-and-shares/0/0/447/) or if you must use MySQL then you will need to use Javascript to listen for clicks and save it with MySQL. To do this check out:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.event.subscribe/

Also check this out:
[Facebook Like button and MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894954/facebook-like-button-and-mysql-database)