# Export Facebook "I like" votes to a database

Tags: facebook, asp-classic, facebook-fql

I'm trying to build an application to let users vote pictures in my site. Users can vote by clicking the "I like" button.
I have to register votes for each picture and store that values in a database. I need this information in order to show those pictures in my web site ordered by votes descending (and I'll pick up the votes from the db).

I don't know how to export those data to the db.
The application will be written in ASP classic.

I've read here [Facebook Like button and MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894954/facebook-like-button-and-mysql-database)
to perform FQL

```
SELECT like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="url is here"
```

There was also the suggestion to read here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat

It says to run this query

```
$facebook->api_client->fql_query('SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="YOUR_SHARE_URL"');
```

My problem is that I work in ASP Classic and I don't know how to run that query.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it seems like you can simply escape you query statement and add it to the url.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/links/

eg.

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+share_count%2C+like_count%2C+comment_count%2C+total_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url%3D%22google.com%22&access_token=2227470867|2.AQCjzTJiS0GEC4Mm.3600.1314694800.0-100001742787554|HvVVWfurhpbzG-j5cS5LHGlkFew

Comment: You should also paste the query separately: `SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="google.com"`. You could also show a method of building (concatenating) the URL, using [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php): `$url = 'https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query='.urlencode($query).'&access_token='.$access_token;`, this would make your post much more readable (and more useful).